# Modifing a URL Validation RegEx

Tags: regex

```
$regex = "_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS";
```

Where do i added my Expression `[A-Za-z0-9.,/&=?:_+#%-]` to allow only these specific characters to be used while keeping the form of the URL as it is made in `$regex`,

I've tried adding it at the beginning after `_^` but it finds every URL an invalid url, That after removing the `_` from the Expression too.

The `$regex` works ok and prevents weird urls like `www..doma@$#n.#@om` but when it comes to the part after that like

`www.domain.com/<script>alert('Hacked')</script>`, It just allows every single special character to be used, So i've decided to allow only Alphanumeric and `. , / & = ? : _ + # % -` since they're used in every URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `[^\s]` with the expression you want `[A-Za-z0-9.,/&=?:_+#%-]`

Example:
https://regex101.com/r/kWB1q1/2

Comment: I've noticed that `_` and `_iuS` was removed, What was the usage of them if the RegEx works without them?

Comment: The _ are used in PHP as delimiters in your case. For more information about delimiters read http://pl.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: iuS are your flags, if you want to know what flags there are and what they stand for, click on the flag icon @ regex101..